# PCLs: "The type or namespace name 'Thread' could not be found"

Tags: .net, portable-class-library

I'm having trouble changing my class library to a PCL in VS 2015 Update 3. A couple of types that should exist are missing, most notably `Thread`. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx) says

- .NET Framework: Available since 1.1
- Portable Class Library: Supported in: portable .NET platforms
- Silverlight: Available since 2.0
- Windows Phone Silverlight: Available since 7.0

My targets seem compatible. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The MSDN documentation is often a little bit misleading when it comes to PCLs. The fact that *Portable Class Libraries* are listed in the *Available in* section is only an indication that the type is available in at least one PCL profile. However, there is no guarantee that the type is available in a specific PCL profile, **even** if the type is available in all target platforms.

The PCL profile you have selected, Profile 49, does **not** support the `Thread` class. If you re-target .NET Framework to 4.0 (PCL Profile 136), `Thread` is available, but practically useless, since most relevant methods are still not supported.

So in short, if you want to target those two platforms, you will not be able to use `Thread` in the PCL library. You will need to place `Thread` functionality in platform-specific libraries instead.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this is so? How can I find out which profiles have a `Thread` class? And how can I set my project to use a particular numbered profile?

Comment: There is a, somewhat outdated, tool called the *PCL Compliance Analyzer* which was developed by Vagif Abilov for the first generation of PCL. This tool should be able yo at least give you a hint, but please note that it is primarily applicable to legacy PCL profiles. You can read about it [here](https://vagifabilov.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/check-your-code-portability-with-pcl-compliance-analyzer/), and the source code is [here](https://github.com/object/PclAnalyzer).